# PHPUnit e Selenium - Como chamar funções específicas do script de teste?

Tags: php, cakephp, selenium-webdriver, phpunit

Preciso criar vários scripts de teste para *WEB* utilizando **PHPUnit** e **Selenium**. Obtive sucesso com meus testes iniciais. Consegui inclusive testar o login e logout de minha página WEB efetivamente.

O problema é que eu só consigo executar todas as funções do script de uma vez, e isso me faz perder muito tempo em um único teste, além de me impedir de reutilizar o código já escrito para outros testes.

Gostaria saber como faço para, em um script de testes como o mostrado abaixo, executar somente algumas funções específicas.

```
<?php

class LoginTest extends PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase
{
 protected function setUp()
 {
    $url = EXAMPLE_URL;
    $this->setBrowser('firefox');
    $this->setBrowserUrl($url);
    $this->prepareSession();
    $this->url(EXAMPLE_URL/users/login);
    $this->currentWindow()->maximize();
    }

private function testTitle($title = null)
{
    if (!$title)
        $title = EXAMPLE_TITLE_LOGIN;
    $this->assertEquals($title,$this->title());
    }

private function testLoginFormExists()
{
    //Verifica se está na tela de login
    $this->testTitle();

    $name = $this->byName('data[User][username]');
    $passwd = $this->byName('data[User][password]');

    $this->assertEquals('',$name->value());
    $this->assertEquals('',$passwd->value());

    }

private function testLoginAction()
{
    //Verifica se o form de login existe
    $this->testLoginFormExists();

    $form = $this->byId('UserLoginForm');
    $action = $form->attribute('action');
    $this->assertEquals(EXAMPLE_URL/users/login, $action);

    $this->byName('data[User][username]')->value('admin');
    $this->byName('data[User][password]')->value('ventovento');

    $form->submit();

    //Verifica se logou corretamente
    $this->testTitle(EXAMPLE_TITLE_HOME);

    }

private function testLogoutAction()
{
    //Verifica se realiza login
    $this->testLoginAction();

    //Realiza logout
    $this->byId('img-logout')->click();

    //Verifica se realizou logout corretamente
    $this->testTitle();
    }

}

?>
```

Para exemplificar melhor o que eu estou querendo fazer: no script acima, eu pretendo chamar somente a função *testLogoutAction()*. Entretanto, quando executo o script, ele executa todas as funções declaradas em ordem.

Isso também acontece quando eu extendo a classe a outra. Por exemplo, no teste a seguir, ele executa todas as funções do código anterior, e depois continua a execução dos testes da respectiva classe.

```
<?php

require_once("LoginTest.php");

class ContasTest extends LoginTest
{ ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use as opções de seleção na linha de comando:

```
$ phpunit -h

Test Selection Options:

  --filter <pattern>        Filter which tests to run.
  --testsuite <pattern>     Filter which testsuite to run.
  --group ...               Only runs tests from the specified group(s).
  --exclude-group ...       Exclude tests from the specified group(s).
  --list-groups             List available test groups.
  --test-suffix ...         Only search for test in files with specified
                            suffix(es). Default: Test.php,.phpt
```

ex:

```
class AssertionTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase{
    /**
     * @group grupo1
     * @author Paulo Henrique
     */
    public function testAssertTrue(){
        $this->assertTrue(2+3==5);
    }

    /**
     * @group grupo2
     */
    public function testAssertFalse(){
        $this->assertFalse(2+2 == 5);
    }
    /**
     * @group grupo2
     * @author Paulo Henrique
     */
    public function testAssertEquals(){
    $this->assertEquals( 2+5, 7, " It should be 7" ); 
    }
}
```

Executando na linha de comando:

**filter** executa somente os testes que atendam a regex que vc escrever. ex:

```
$ phpunit --filter 'AssertTrue' AssertionsTest.php 
PHPUnit 3.7.22 by Sebastian Bergmann.

.

Time: 0 seconds, Memory: 3.25Mb

OK (1 test, 1 assertion)
```

**group** executa somente os testes que tenham o annotation **@group**.

```
$ phpunit --color --group grupo2 AssertionsTest.php 
PHPUnit 3.7.22 by Sebastian Bergmann.

..

Time: 0 seconds, Memory: 3.25Mb

OK (2 tests, 2 assertions)
```

Além da annotation @group, você pode rodar todos os testes escritos por um só desenvolvedor, se passar ,como grupo, o nome da annotation **@author**.

```
$ phpunit --color --group "Paulo Henrique" AssertionsTest.php
PHPUnit 3.7.22 by Sebastian Bergmann.

..

Time: 0 seconds, Memory: 3.25Mb

OK (2 tests, 2 assertions)
```

Você encontrará mais detalhes na [documentação](http://phpunit.de/manual/current/pt_br/textui.html).

Comment: Ótimo! Funcionou muito bem dessa forma. Desde já agradeço.
Sabe dizer se há como usar esse filtro através da interface de testes (Test Suite) do CakePHP, ou é possível somente pela linha de comando mesmo?

Comment: Não sei. Não uso CakePHP. :)